# Replace Java throw exception with custom message and continue

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throw

My Java `for loop` checks for different `id` in `ids() String[] array` as:

**BackTest.java**

```
.....
    for (String id: ids()) {
         //..do something
         addResult(result(id));
    }
```

where `addResult()` is adding the result to some Java `map`. Here if the `id does not exist`, i.e http `status!=200` then I am throwing a new exception as shown in the following snippet:

**Api.Java**

```
......
     if (status != 200) {
                    String error = "No additional error message received";
                    if (result != null && result instanceof JSONObject) {
                        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) result;
                        if (obj.containsKey("error")) {
                            error = '"' + (String) obj.get("error") + '"';
                        }
                    }

                    throw new ApiException(
                            "API returned HTTP " + status +
                            "(" + error + ")"
                            );
       }
```

Now in my first `for` loop, if the first id in the loop `does not exist`, then I am throwing an exception and this makes `my entire process to fail` and it fails to check for the `further ids as a part of id array`. How do I make sure that even if it fails on first id in an array, code should continue to check for further ids?

I can think of replacing `throw new exception` with try-catch block. An example would be good.

Comment: You can catch exceptions and handle them with `try`/`catch`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yeah, you are right.

Comment: So: `try {addResult(result(id));} catch(ApiException e) {e.printStackTrace();}`?

Comment: Does not answer my question. So, `addResult() method is failing for first id in the loop` and so `entire` loop is not getting executed. How this fails? When I do addResult(), it takes me to the `Api.java` and it checks for `if(status != 200)` as shown in my original question. Then I throw ApiException there. addResult() call is not in Api.java.

Comment: Updating my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle an exception like so;

```
for(String id : ids()) {
    try {
        addResult(result(id));
    } catch(ApiException e) {
        System.err.println("Oops, something went wrong for ID "+id+"! Here's the stack trace:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This will catch the exception, which stops it from propagating past this point and therefore ending the loop, and it will print a message and the stack trace instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to continue processing the rest of your list/array without the overhead of throwing a new exception, then I would look into using the `continue` keyword.

The `continue` keyword was designed for situations like this. It causes the program's execution to immediately return to the start of the closest loop and test its condition. I would suggest using the following setup.

```
    for(String id : ids()) {

        //do stuff...

        if(status != 200) {
            //write to data logger, etc...
            continue;
        }

        addResult(result(id));
    }
```

Some do not like using `continue` as too many of them can generate messy code. However, if used sparingly, they can help cut down on the amount of code within a loop.